# Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float

Tags: t-sql

I am saving time entered by user like 45 minutes as 75 minutes and then when displaying the data back to the user, i need to convert it back into 45 minutes. however it's a float column and i was trying the following t-sql statement to convert it back:

```
UPDATE  #T1
SET     #T1.HOURS = ( CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(mi,(#T1.Hours * 60 ), '00:00')) )
WHERE   #T1.HOURS <= 24
```

but it's throwing me the following error:

```
Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float
```

i have also tried to convert the #T1.Hours value to string by using the following function

```
STR(#T1.Hours, 18,2)
```

but the error thrown is still the same

Can anyone help me resolve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following.

```
SUBSTRING(T1.HOURS, 0, CHARINDEX('.',T1.HOURS)) + ':' + (SUBSTRING(T1.HOURS,
                                    CHARINDEX('.',
                                              T1.HOURS)
                                    + 1,
                                    LEN(T1.HOURS)) * 60) / 100
```

I also had to convert the T1.Hours to string by

```
    Str(T1.Hours,18,2) and use a LTrim function
```